# Phone Gap , Blackberry environment reference external JS file

Tags: blackberry, cordova

I am using Phone Gap Blackberry environment for creating apps targeted OS6.0 & above.
In the index.html, inside the head tag i am referencing the external JS file, which actually contains the data needed for my application.
EG: www. google .com/js/data.js

In the project config.xml i have also referenced the the site
EG:< access subdomains="true" uri="http :// www.google.com" />

The issue here is, i dont see the data.js file being called. This works fine with Android & Iphone environment.
Am i doing something wrong here???

Comment: What do you mean  by "i dont see the data.js file being called" ?

Comment: Let me give the logic of what i am doing... 
Data.js file has two variables, fileversion and data... 
when the index.html loads, i check whether the local storage version 
and the fileversion are same, if not i am loading the local storage 
with the data variable...  so i dont see the fileversion variable being set or do i see the latest data being loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your config.xml, you need to also provide access to the google.com domain, otherwise your app won't get access to google.com and won't be able to download the script file. From your post, it looks like you only provided access to nyigf.com.

You need to add an additional  element to your config.xml, i.e.

```
<access subdomains="true" uri="http://www.google.com" />
```

Comment: sorry for the typo...i have given the correct access in the config.xml, but still no luck....

Comment: OK, i figured out the issue... the file is being called, but the file size is 392KB and Blackberry seems to have some issues when downloading the file more than 128KB..Any thoughts

Comment: this is a common problem I have to deal with all the time when developing for BlackBerry. I work on a BlackBerry mobile web application (accessed simply through the BlackBerry browser) and I see this problem all the time. It's tough making an app when you have hard JavaScript limits like this, isn't it? Drives me nuts. If you get a third party BlackBerry app called 'ShowEventLog' (logs system events in a clear fashion), you can see the JavaScript interpreter throwing "OutOfMemoryException" all over the place eventually. #fail